# How to use DocumentDB behind a Proxy in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In NodeJS I`m trying to connect to a Cosmos DB using the Documentdb library, as the getting starter of the azure documentation says in the TODO List Example. [Tutorial Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application)

If I use an Internet that is not behind a proxy it works.

This is the connection code:

```
var DocumentDBClient = require('documentdb').DocumentClient;

var docDbClient = new DocumentDBClient(config.host, {
    masterKey: config.authKey
});
```

But when I'm behind a proxy, the connection never occur's. I`m getting an "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"

In other node JS apps, if I want to make a request of a webservice, I just configure the proxy for the request. For example with request:

```
request = require('request').defaults({
  proxy:'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@proxy.url.com:8080',
});
```

Is there a way to configure the proxy in DocumentDB to connect to the DB in Azure  (NodeJS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not personally tried it but I was going through the source code of the SDK and found out that `ConnectionPolicy` has a parameter called `ProxyUrl`. Can you try something like the following:

```
var connectionPolicy = new DocumentBase.ConnectionPolicy();
connectionPolicy.ProxyUrl = 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@proxy.url.com:8080';
var docDbClient = new DocumentDBClient(config.host, {
    masterKey: config.authKey
}, connectionPolicy);
```

Comment: I added this line with the proper proxy url, and doesn't work. Still have the same issue and Timeout problem

Comment: Sorry....my bad! You would actually need to create an instance of `ConnectionPolicy` and pass that in the constructor for `DocumentDBClient`. I have updated my answer with modified code. Can you please try that. You may need to import (or require) `DocumentBase`.