# Can I able to use default proxy for cosmos db project

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I have done a service using cosmos db and asp.net core .For WiFi it is working but when i try with default proxy it give the error.

```
SocketException: Resource temporarily unavailable
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

DocumentClient Create code example:

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> FetchProductListAsync(
         Guid? itemId)
        {

            var feedOptions =
                  new FeedOptions
                  {
                      MaxItemCount = -1,
                      EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                  };

            var query =
                $"SELECT  product.Id,product.Name,product.MethodOfPreparation,product.Addons,product.CurrentQuantity,product.Tag,product.Unit,product.Price FROM catalog join industry in catalog.Industy join category in industry.Category join Subcategory in category.Subcategory  join product in Subcategory.Product where catalog.id = '" + itemId + "'";

            var queryDefinition =
                new SqlQuerySpec(query);



            var orderDocumentQuery =
                 _docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Product>(
                     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                         _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), queryDefinition, feedOptions)
                     .AsDocumentQuery();

           var childrenSqlQuery = _docClient.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query).ToString();


            Console.WriteLine(childrenSqlQuery);
            Console.WriteLine(childrenSqlQuery);
            var orderList =
                new List<Product>();


            while (orderDocumentQuery.HasMoreResults)
            {
                orderList.AddRange(
                    await orderDocumentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync<Product>());
                Console.WriteLine(orderList);
            }

            return orderList;
        }
```

I am using DucumentDb.Core 2.4.1,Please give me idea .

Comment: Can you share how are you creating the DocumentClient instance? Any code snippet?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IYphYOPU3M7BUNQlJDV5rZzhI7zDz1FM?usp=sharing

Comment: here i provide my full code

Answer (score 0):

In node js sdk, you could set the ProxyUrl property directly.([How to use DocumentDB behind a Proxy in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425340/how-to-use-documentdb-behind-a-proxy-in-nodejs))

However,it doesn't have such properties in the [.NET sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy?view=azure-dotnet). You could try below configuration from this case:[CosmosDB C# SDK ProyUrl missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153665/cosmosdb-c-sharp-sdk-proyurl-missing)

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

However,i noticed that it only supports .net,not for .net core,from this [trace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/db8b5e35-8a41-4eb3-9db1-f2e8cdc839fa/specifying-proxy-for-documentclient-error-407?forum=azurecosmosdb).So, please refer to this case:[asp.net core defaultProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637592/asp-net-core-defaultproxy)